# System hang when mounting btrfs

Tags: mount, btrfs

I have a btrfs filesystem that includes 3 disks in raid0:

```
 # btrfs fi show /dev/sdb1 
 Label: 'disco_backup'  uuid: 10726648-202c-4792-82d4-5d0911cce762
         Total devices 3 FS bytes used 8.05TiB
         devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 3.64TiB path /dev/sdb1
         devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 2.73TiB path /dev/sdd1
         devid    3 size 1.82TiB used 1.82TiB path /dev/sdc1
```

I uses it as backup. I have a subvolume for the backup and each new backup is a snapshot of the previous one and is updated by rsync.

The filesystem was nearly full. I deleted some snapshots but the disk space was not updated. Then I enabled quotas on the disk for viewing the used space:

```
# btrfs quota enable /mnt/bacup
```

When I did this after a few minutes the system hanged (I think due to out of memory). After this, I has not been able to mount the disk. Every time I try to mount it the system hangs.

[image: kernel message]

I added many swap space (300Gb) but it stills hang when mounting. I tried running btrfsck but it does not report errors.

Kernel 4.4.59

btrfs-progs 4.4.1

Any help please?

Comment: This is really a bad asked question, with no information about the distribution and used kernel version whatsoever.

Comment: Added version info

Kernel 4.4.59

btrfs-progs 4.4.1

Comment: Try using a decent kernel like 4.10 at least, Btrfs had a nasty quota bug in those lower kernel versions and look for yourself how it turns out.

Comment: No screenshots of your terminals. Copy the text to the question and use the code formatting option.

Comment: @MarcStürmer Do you have any links to that quota bug? Think I might be running into it.

Comment: As I understand it, BtrFS does reconstruction in background after a snapshot is being removed (snapshots use shared blocks), so it could take some time until you see the effect. You seems (you don't wrote that) you interrupted the activity (by reset?) while not knowing what's going on ("I think due to out of memory": You should have looked in the syslog instead of "thinking" or guessing). My guess is that the filesystem needed recovery of some type. Also, considering the early stage of BtrFS at that time, not every interruption may be recoverable.